# Modify a text file in server?

Tags: ssh, ftp

I need to modify the ape.conf file in my apache server. However when I access it through filezilla the file is read only. How do I modify it? Can I change permissions with SSH? Or what would be the correct way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Please stop referring to this as your "apache server" and start telling us what operating system you are running, as well as using appropriate tags. Your question as written applies equally to all operating systems that can run Apache, yet the details of the answer can be different for each.

Answer (score 1):

if you can connect through ssh ... why don't you modify your file with a text editor ?

Comment: I don't know how to do it...

Comment: step 1) ssh loginname@machine step2) cd /whereFileIs step3) nano fileName